# How can I serialize an object array server side using c#?

Tags: c#, ajax, json, serialization, webforms

I need to return an object array from server side. How can I serialize the example below so that it looks like that using c# and webforms?

```
var word_list = [
          {text: "Lorem", weight: 15},
          {text: "Ipsum", weight: 9, url: "http://jquery.com/", title: "I can haz URL"},
          {text: "Dolor", weight: 6},
          {text: "Sit", weight: 7},
          {text: "Amet", weight: 5}
          // ...other words
      ];
```

I have tried the following, but it adds quotes to the properties and doesn't seem to work.

```
 JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

Comment: FYI, the JSON spec requires that properties be wrapped with double quotes

Comment: This plugin seems to not adhere to the spec

Comment: @KenBrowning: It's not JSON, it's a JavaScript *object literal* that is being assigned to a JavaScript variable. It's not supposed to adhere to the spec.

Comment: Sorry, I was explaining why JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize adds quotes to the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up returning a json object from the server-side and then looping through that to create the proper formatting.